# how to populate intermediate table in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I have two tables with a many-to-many relationship. So I created an intermediate table, but I can't find a way to populate this table correctly because I can't set a correct list from my data.

I have a list of 'courses' : each 'course' can have one or several categories.
So my table looks like this :

```
|idcourses|title|date|categories|
|----|----|----|----|
|700|title1|01012021|[54]|
|701|title2|01022021|[54]|
|702|title3|01032021|[48]|
|868|title4|01042021|[47, 52, 54]|
```

If I try a map like this :

```
val myMap = coursesList.map { itcategory to it.idcourses}.distinct()
```

I have this kind of result :

```
([54], 700), ([54], 701), ([48], 702), ([47, 52, 54], 868)
```

The whole "[47, 52, 54]" is considered as one string but I want it to be split so I can have this :

```
([54], 700), ([54], 701), ([48], 702), ([47], 868), ([52], 868), ([54], 868)
```

Does anyone know how to achieve this ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you may be trying to do this the wrong way as it appears that your intermediate table has a column where you are expecting a list of category id's.

You cannot have a column that is a list/array it has to be a single object.

**However** rather than try to fix that, what would typically be used for an intermediate table is a table that primarily has a single row per mapping. That is **two columns** that make up a mapping. Where the two columns are a composite primary key.

- other columns that have data specific to the mapping can be used.
- In your case one column to map/reference/relate/associate to the course and an second column to map the course.

For example, say you have the Course Table and the Category Table per:-

```
@Entity
data class Course(
    @PrimaryKey
    val idcourses: Long? = null,
    val title: String,
    val date: String
)
```

and

```
@Entity
data class Category(
    @PrimaryKey
    val idcategories: Long? = null,
    val name: String
)
```

Then you could have the intermediate table as :-

```
@Entity(primaryKeys = ["idcoursesmap","idcategoriesmap"])
data class CourseCategoryMap(
    val idcoursesmap: Long,
    @ColumnInfo(index = true)
    val idcategoriesmap: Long
)
```

- the index on the **idcategoriesmap** will likely improve the efficiency. Room would also issue a warning.
- you may wish to consider defining Foreign Key constraints to enforce referential integrity. None have been included for brevity.

This is sufficient for a many-many relationship.

You would probably want to retrieve Courses with the Categories so you would probably want a POJO for this such as:-

```
data class CourseWithCategories(
    @Embedded
    val course: Course,
    @Relation(
        entity = Category::class,
        parentColumn = "idcourses",
        entityColumn = "idcategories",
        associateBy = Junction(
            value = CourseCategoryMap::class,
            parentColumn = "idcoursesmap",
            entityColumn = "idcategoriesmap"
        )
    )
    val categories: List<Category>
)
```

Here's some Dao's that would or may be wanted/useful:-

```
abstract class AllDao {
    @Insert(onConflict = IGNORE) // Insert single Category
    abstract fun insert(category: Category): Long
    @Insert(onConflict = IGNORE) // Insert Single Course
    abstract fun insert(course: Course): Long
    @Insert(onConflict = IGNORE) // Insert Single CourseCategoryMap
    abstract fun insert(courseCategoryMap: CourseCategoryMap): Long
    /* Inserts many course category maps */
    @Insert(onConflict = IGNORE)
    abstract fun insert(courseCategoryMaps: List<CourseCategoryMap>): List<Long>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM course WHERE course.title=:courseTitle")
    abstract fun getCourseByTitle(courseTitle: String): Course
    @Query("SELECT * FROM category WHERE category.name LIKE :categoryMask")
    abstract fun getCategoriesByNameMask(categoryMask: String): List<Category>
    /* For retrieving courses with all the courses categories */
    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * FROM course")
    abstract fun getAllCoursesWithCategories(): List<CourseWithCategories>

    @Transaction
    @Query("")
    fun insertManyCataegoriesForACourseByIds(idcourse: Long,categories: List<Long>) {
        for (categoryId: Long in categories) {
            insert(CourseCategoryMap(idcourse,categoryId))
        }
    }

    // Anoher possibility
    @Transaction
    @Query("")
    fun insertManyCategoriesForACourse(course: Course, categories: List<Category>) {
        val categoryIds = ArrayList<Long>()
        for (c: Category in categories) {
            categoryIds.add(c.idcategories!!)
        }
        insertManyCataegoriesForACourseByIds(course.idcourses!!,categoryIds)
    }
}
```

**Demonstration**

To demonstrate the above, a pretty standard class annotated with @Database :-

```
const val DATABASE_NAME = "the_database.db"
const val DATABASE_VERSION =1
@Database(entities = [Course::class,Category::class,CourseCategoryMap::class], exportSchema = false, version = DATABASE_VERSION)
abstract class TheDatabase: RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun getAllDao(): AllDao

    companion object {
        @Volatile
        private var instance: TheDatabase? = null
        fun getInstance(context: Context): TheDatabase {
            if (instance == null) {
                instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context,TheDatabase::class.java, DATABASE_NAME)
                    .allowMainThreadQueries()
                    .build()
            }
            return instance as TheDatabase
        }
    }
}
```

And activity code to replicate what it looks like your are attempting (but twice to show 2 ways of mapping, the second using category id's that are 20 greater then the first) :-

```
lateinit var db: TheDatabase
lateinit var dao: AllDao
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    db = TheDatabase.getInstance(this)
    dao = db.getAllDao()

    dao.insert(Course(idcourses = 700,title = "title1", date = "01012021"))
    dao.insert(Course(701,"title2","01022021"))
    dao.insert(Course(702,"title3","01032021"))
    dao.insert(Course(868,"title4","01042021"))

    // add quite a few categories for demo
    for(i in 30..300) {
        dao.insert(Category(i.toLong(),"Category${i}"))
    }

    //example of what you are trying to do (first)
    var currentCourse = dao.getCourseByTitle("title1")
    dao.insertManyCataegoriesForACourseByIds(currentCourse.idcourses!!, listOf(54))
    dao.insertManyCataegoriesForACourseByIds(dao.getCourseByTitle("title2").idcourses!!, listOf(54))
    dao.insertManyCataegoriesForACourseByIds(dao.getCourseByTitle("title3").idcourses!!, listOf(48))
    dao.insertManyCataegoriesForACourseByIds(dao.getCourseByTitle("title4").idcourses!!, listOf(47,52,54))

    // second (does the same but uses categroyids 20 greater than the first)
    val coursecategorymaplist = listOf<CourseCategoryMap>(
        CourseCategoryMap(700,74),
        CourseCategoryMap(701,74),
        CourseCategoryMap(702,68),
        CourseCategoryMap(868,67),
        CourseCategoryMap(868,72),
        CourseCategoryMap(868,74)
    )
    dao.insert(coursecategorymaplist)

    // Extract results
    for (cwc: CourseWithCategories in dao.getAllCoursesWithCategories()) {
        Log.d("DBINFO","Course is ${cwc.course.title}, date is ${cwc.course.date} it has ${cwc.categories.size} categories they are:-")
        for (c: Category in cwc.categories) {
            Log.d("DBINFO","\tCategory is ${c.name}")
        }
    }
}
```

**Results**

The log includes (note double the number of categories):-

```
D/DBINFO: Course is title1, date is 01012021 it has 2 categories they are:-
D/DBINFO:   Category is Category54
D/DBINFO:   Category is Category74
D/DBINFO: Course is title2, date is 01022021 it has 2 categories they are:-
D/DBINFO:   Category is Category54
D/DBINFO:   Category is Category74
D/DBINFO: Course is title3, date is 01032021 it has 2 categories they are:-
D/DBINFO:   Category is Category48
D/DBINFO:   Category is Category68
D/DBINFO: Course is title4, date is 01042021 it has 6 categories they are:-
D/DBINFO:   Category is Category47
D/DBINFO:   Category is Category52
D/DBINFO:   Category is Category54
D/DBINFO:   Category is Category67
D/DBINFO:   Category is Category72
D/DBINFO:   Category is Category74
```

The Database

The Course Table :-

[image]

The Category Table (partial)

[image]

The CourseCategoryMap (intermediate table)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for all the explanations. I already had the dao and Roomdatabases. But my intermediate table is still empty... The log says "The loop iterates over values of type CourseCatMap but the parameter is declared to be CourseWithCategories"

Comment: Sorry I had it wrong in the dao. So no error on the logcat while running, but my CourseCatMap Table is still empty... :(

Comment: @gkaro hard to know what you done/used and therefore why you are the table is or appears to be empty. As such only guesses could be made as to the issue you have. Perhaps consider updating you question or asking another question showing all the relevant code.

Comment: thanks for your help